# "The number of inquiries was also a factor, but effect was not significant"

Tags: credit-score

I monitor my (Experian) credit and see some factors are helping and some factors are hurting my score, which is borderline "Excellent".  Of the 9 line items reported, one is, "The number of inquiries was also a factor, but effect was not significant".  I have not been applying for credit recently, so now I wonder.

How far back are inquiries considered?  Several years?  One year?  One month?

And within whatever time frame is correct, at what number does it not hurt at all?

Comment: Which service are you using to see your credit score?

Comment: Experian reports this.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say “Experian reports this,” are you reading this on experian.com, or is this a credit score from another service based on Experian’s credit report data?

Comment: usaa.experiandirect.com is the web page, so I take it that is first-hand data.

Comment: Most (all?) of the reporting agencies will include details of hard inquiries on your report for 2 years, and scoring models will typically factor those inquiries into your score for a period of one year, with the overall effect diminishing throughout that year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different credit scores, and each has its own secret formula. Based on [this page from USAA](https://www.usaa.com/inet/wc/faq_credit_score_index?akredirect=true), I believe that the credit score you are seeing through USAA is VantageScore 3.0. This is different from the more famous FICO score (which is used by most lenders) in a number of ways. One key difference between the two is how recent credit inquiries affect your score.

According to [credit.com](http://blog.credit.com/2017/12/fico-v-vantagescore-5-differences-you-should-know-64279/), deduplication is different between the two. When you are shopping around for a mortgage or car loan, you may have multiple credit inquiries in a short amount of time. Deduplication is the process by which the credit score detects this activity and considers it all one inquiry. The article claims that FICO uses a 45-day window for deduplication, but VantageScore only uses a 15-day window.

Credit inquiries remain on your credit report for 2 years, but according to [this article on Experian.com](https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/how-long-do-inquiries-impact-my-scores-2/), credit inquiries only affect your FICO score for a maximum of 1 year. I haven’t found any articles that report the length of time that inquiries affect your VantageScore.

Comment: I've had similar results as you described while playing with the myfico simulator: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/77630/17718