# Dealership ran my credit and then texted me and told me the truck was priced wrong. What can I do?

Tags: united-states, scams, credit-report, auto-loan

Called a dealership to buy a truck over the phone. I told him I wanted it and that I was going to have them finance it. First time over the phone purchase because of COVID-19
San Antonio, Texas
Price was $27,995 then it was $36,990.
Red

Comment: what is is included in the $36,990 price. Does that include taxes, title, registration, extra warranty, undercoating,....? These might not have been included in the original price you saw.

Comment: *price was ... then it was* - What has happened?

Comment: Consider making them print out the credit report and hand it to you (if they didn't already), since I believe they have to if you request it. Note that multiple auto loan credit inquires within a short timeframe shouldn't negatively affect your credit beyond the initial hit. More info here: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/109936/17718

Answer (score 8):

You can tell them you will buy it at the originally agreed lower price, and that you won't buy it at the higher price.

Of course, they may tell you they won't sell it at the lower price, and will only sell it at the higher price, and you will end up not buying the truck. Or they may offer a "compromise" price between the two, and maybe you will buy the truck.

Comment: This.  They will try this. They've hooked you and now they are betting that you will agree to a higher price.  This is a bait and switch.  They're switching now.  I don't think they ever intended to sell the truck at the original price.  The plan has been to get to the financing phase and jack up the price.  They would have done the same thing if you said you were paying cash.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of things that may be happening here.

1. The new price is simply the old price plus taxes, fees and/or other extras. Taxes are of course non-negotiable, and some fees are considered 'compulsory' (usually delivery charges), but the new price may also include "extras" that they want you to buy but you don't need to - like rustproofing, extra warranty. Get them to give you a detailed breakdown of what is included in the new price. In some jurisdictions car prices must by law be advertized including all 'compulsory' fees. In any case, a price is always negotiable, and you can choose to accept the new price, refuse it, or try to negotiate it down.
2. The dealership genuinely made a mistake. This is possible but very rare. In any case the dealer ought to be open to some negotiation for having quoted you this price in the first place.
3. The dealership has increased the price because of your credit record. This is also unlikely because they are more likely to change the terms of the financing, and even then only if your credit is bad, which you should know. Ask specifically if this is the case. You could also try offering them cash and arrange your own financing. In any case the price is negotiable.
4. The dealer is playing bait and switch. They advertize a low price to draw in buyers and then raise the price once they have someone interested. This is exceptionally shady practice and illegal in some jurisdictions, but quite common in places where it is legal (and not uncommon in places where it is illegal). The easy way to find this out is to have someone else phone the dealer and inquire about the truck. If they still quote your first price then they are playing bait and switch. If this is illegal where you are the authorities would want to know, and even if it is legal local media may be interested. I would refuse to deal with a dealer who did this, since they will also be dishonest in other ways.