# Will getting a second credit card raise my credit score like the first card I got did?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score

I just got my first credit card a few months ago and it had a huge effect on my score, raising it by about 90 points. Now my score is hovering around 600. I would like to get it up to 650 to increase my chances of renting an apartment. Will getting a second credit card increase my score the same way as the first one?

Comment: Are you keeping your usage rate down, and paying the whole bill when due?

Comment: Yup less than 10% and all payments on time

Comment: Your score *might* go up, since your usage would go down, but if it's already at 10% that might be meaningless.

Comment: Do you have have any "strikes" on your credit history?

Comment: A related question: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126424/credit-score-dropped-73-points-after-applying-for-a-new-card?rq=1

Comment: Most likely, you simply don't have a long enough credit history for a significantly higher score.

Comment: Somewhat non sequitur: For those with good credit, with the economy opening up, credit card companies are bending over backwards with decent bonuses for opening up a credit card.

Comment: @ronjohn I have 2 collection accounts on trans union and 1 on equifax if that's what you mean by strikes.

Comment: @chepner no I definitely do not have a long enough credit history but credit karma also says that more accounts is a good thing. They recommend something crazy, like over 10 open accounts but like said e em just getting the one secured card gave me like 90 point boost

Comment: @David Among other services, Credit Karma lets you shop for credit cards on their site. If I'm not mistaken, they collect a referral fee when someone gets a credit card though their site. So it would not surprise me if they recommend opening new accounts. I would also be very surprised if more than 2 or 3 accounts would significantly increase your score.

Comment: @David that's exactly what I mean by strikes.

Comment: Cool thanks for all your guys' advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update : I ended up getting the second credit card and my score only went up by 2 points on my trans union and equifax vantage 3.0 score.